# Problema de registro y control de acceso a una página de formulario

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una web de un Club en donde los socios deben de entrar a consultar o editar un formulario, y quiero que todo aquel que habiendo hecho logging previamente y entre en dicho formulario, (aunque solo lo abra) se quede grabada en una tabla de la base de datos quien ha entrado, la fecha y hora correspondiente.

Hasta aquí es fácil, pues me hace un insert en la base de datos de quién ha sido y cuándo. El problema es que me registra el mismo usuario varias veces (3 o 4 veces), en intervalos entre 0,6 a 1  microsegundos. ¿A que puede ser debido y que podría hacer para evitarlo?.

Utilizo wordpress última versión. En el host me dicen que no puede hacer nada.

Adjunto el código, que como se puede ver no hay bucles, también adjunto captura de lo que recibo en la BD y como es la estructura de la tabla.

El código es bastante simple, las variables son de prueba.

```html
<html>
  <?php 
include("conexion.php");  // parametros de conexión BD 
    $dp = 'MDP';    
    $Frm = 'Mis Datos';
    $vDni = '123456789V';
    $name_usuario = 'Miguel';
$sql= mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO PRU_Tmanteni   (tipo_dato,usuario,name_usuario,formulario)
    VALUES ('".$dp."','".$vDni."','".$name_usuario."','".$Frm."')");
   ?>
</html>
```

[image: Captura de como llegan los datos]

[image: Estructura de la Tabla]

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte de manera mas eficaz, deberías dejar el código de ejemplo. Para ver si se detecta algún fallo. Es muy difícil dar un motivo de error o una solución sin conocer la estructura. Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y añadas el código.

Comment: Buenas!
Seguramente tu INSERT se está ejecutando repetidas veces según cargas el formulario. Revisa que no tengas bucles cuando lo ejecutas, sino, yo te propondría controlar cada cuanto permites realizar un INSERT por usuario con algun tipo de cookie temportal.
Saludos!

Comment: Ok , reformulo la pregunta de nuevo